# Android Passing Custom Class Instance Between Activities

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a class called `XsDevice()` which is initialised in my `MainActivity` this class contains a bunch of callback methods and also a `LiveData` variable which I need to access in my `MeasuringActivity` to observe.

In my `MainActivity` I can observe the live data without any issue. But I want to use the below code in my `MeasuringActivity`

```
xsDeviceClass.freeAccDataLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<Float>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ArrayList<Float> freeAccData) {
        Log.d("Test", "Hello");
    }
});
```

I now need to pass the `xsDeviceClass` which was initialised in `MainActivity` - `private XsDevice xsDeviceClass = new XsDevice();` to my `MeasuringActivity`

My `XsDevice` class implements `Serializable` and I tried to pass the class over the the `MeasuringActivity` by doing the following

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MeasuringActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("XsDevice", xsDeviceClass);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

But when I try and switch view I get this error `Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.a3dmotionjavaapp.XsDevice)`

Here is my XsDevice class code

```
public class XsDevice implements XsensDotDeviceCb, Serializable {
    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Float>> accelerationData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public LiveData<ArrayList<Float>> freeAccDataLiveData = accelerationData;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onXsensDotDataChanged(String s, XsensDotData xsensDotData) {
        ArrayList<Float> result = new ArrayList();

        for (Float freeAcc: xsensDotData.getFreeAcc()) {
            result.add(freeAcc);
        }
        accelerationData.postValue(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is not directly possible. It is not quite clear what role `XsDevice` plays in common Android architecture patterns, but perhaps it should be made available via a repository singleton, one that viewmodels of both activities can access.

Comment: @CommonsWare Im using an SDK which connected sensors to your devices and then reads measurement data. When I connect a device `XsensDotDevice xsDevice = new XsensDotDevice(this, sensor, xsDeviceClass);` the `xsDeviceClass` is defined as the class where all the callback functions are located. In all honesty im new to android development so Im not sure where this fits in with common Android architecture. Am I able to create a Repo which the `onXsensDotDataChanged` posts data to and the create a `ViewModel` which `MeasuringActivity` observes?

Comment: It would seem like a repository is a reasonable approach. The repository would be responsible for interacting with `XsDevice` and `XsensDotDevice` objects and exposing a clean API to your viewmodels (and from there to your activities and fragments). The idea would be that the repository would hide as much of the detail as possible, so that if/when Xsens changes their SDK, or you decide to switch to some different SDK, most of the changes would be in the repository, not the rest of the app. And, a repository singleton can publish data (`LiveData`, RxJava, etc.) to multiple viewmodels.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the help so far. Sorry to be a massive pain but is there any chance you could provide an answer with an example of what the repository should look like? I have spent the last 2 days trying to figure this out and I know I'll end up making more mistakes ahah.

Comment: You can see examples of repositories in Java [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v1.0/DiceLight) and [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v1.0/Weather), among other projects in that repo (all covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack)). Those are all set up as ordinary Java singletons. If you are using a dependency inversion framework (e.g., Dagger), it will have its own approach for setting up singletons.